# Erro ao rodar programa: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java

Ao rodar meu programa estou recebendo este erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: TestaContador : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Estas são as minhas classes:

- **Conta.java**:

```java
public class Conta {

    static int contador;

    Conta() {
        Conta.contador ++;
    }

}
```

- **TestaContador.java:**

```java
public class TestaContador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println (" Contador : " + Conta.contador);     

        System.out.println (" Contador : " + Conta.contador);

        System.out.println (" Contador : " + Conta.contador);
    }

}
```

Comment: Em que pacote (`package`) está localizada a tua classe `Conta` ?

Comment: src --> (default package)

Comment: Move a classe `Conta` para o pacote `testcontador`, ou cria um pacote com um nome diferente.

Comment: O mesmo erro continua.

Comment: Aparentemente foi um erro do Eclipse.

Comment: Resolveste o problema ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acredito que esta mensagem de erro quer dizer que é necessário o Java 8

- No Eclipse acredito que o caminho seja este <kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Java</kbd> > <kbd>Compiler</kbd> então procure o  *Compiler compliance level* e defina para 1.8 (acredito eu, me corrija se eu estiver enganado).

  Acredito que você também pode trocar o valor de `settings` no arquivo de "preferencias": `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`.

  Por exemplo: `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8`
- No *IntelliJ IDEA* selecione <kbd>project</kbd> > <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Build Execution Deployment</kbd> > <kbd>Compiler</kbd> e em *Java Compiler* vá até *target byte code* e troque o valor para 1.8
- Se for compilar via terminal ou cmd, pode usar o target:

  ```
  javac -target 1.8 HelloWorld.java
  ```

Eu ainda não uso o Java8, por isto não tenho certeza se é 1.8, corrija-me se confundi algo, faz algum tempo que não trabalho com java.

(Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)

Fontes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/1518921
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33494080/1518921
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13296403/1518921

Comment: Isto acontece devido a forma de compilação. O compilador java tem algumas opções (neste caso `source` e `target`: [veja detalhes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCGAJDC)) Em IDEs é comum elas configurarem o `target` para a mesma versão JDK, então mesmo um código sendo passível de rodar em versão anterior irá dar erro =/ Um target `1.7` rodará **A PARTIR** dela. Forçar um *target*  superior do necessário fere a portabilidade, gerando erros desnecessários. A sua resposta resolve, mas o porque deve ser claro :)

Comment: @BrunoCésar Obrigado, excelente link!